# How do I create `/orders/:id/detail` path in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I would like to create a path `/orders/{order_id}/detail` using react-router. How do I do this on the `<Route />` component and also when using the `<Link />` to navigate to the path.

Currently I have it like this
`<Route exact path='/orders/:id' component={OrderDetails} />`

but I want it like this
`<Route exact path='/orders/:id/detail' component={OrderDetails} />`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this route:

```
<Route exact path='/orders/:id/detail' component={OrderDetails} />
```

is correct, its going to render the `OrderDetails` component on this uri:

```
/orders/whatEverId/details
```

the point is the navigation to this url to render that component, for that you need to know that every component that rendered with react router directly has three extra props, `location`, `match` and `history`, and you can get them from `this.props` automatically if you are using class based components, if you are using function component you need to use their hook called `useParams` hook that `react-router` provides and ddestructure  the parameter that you want from url.

more info is [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)